# Salesforce as IdP error - Invalid HTTP method

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, identity-provider

I'm completely new to SSO, so please bear with me...

I have built an application (Service Provider) and I want to use Salesforce as the SSO IdP using SAML 2.0.

When being redirected to Salesforce to authenticate the user, I get a 'Single Sign On Error: Invalid HTTP method' error and the page URL ends with 'SamlError?idpError=1505'

> I have included my configuration[Salesforce Connected App Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igVIp.png)

Comment: If you are an SP starting the process, SP-initiated post endpoint should be used, which is a POST. Any other verb will give you the error.

Comment: Agreed with @codebrane. Please let us know which HTTP method are you using when issuing the SAML request.